nohup output got truncated
I am working on a script to get output from a command for further actions.
I used subprocess to get the output and nohup to run the script in background.
The script run well with python python3 script.py. However, if I run nohup python3 script.py the output seem to be truncated.
For example:
python3 script.py:
C1               C2                     C3
obj1             123.123516123516412    lkjlahsglkasdlgahletawegasdg
obj2             100.987519237059123    sadgashaerhwerjhergegergerg

nohup python3 script.py
C1               C2              C3
obj1             123.1235....    lkjlahsgl....
obj2             100.9875....    sadgashae....

Below is my code:

command = ['command']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, text=True)
output = p.stdout.read()
decode = output.decode('utf-8')

org1 = dict()
org2 = dict()

for line in decode.splitlines():
        *work with lines*

I tried using OS instead of subprocess but still the same. I guess something wrong with stdout and nohup.
What should I do to nohup python3 script.py get the full string?
